# Can't dispose StreamSocket

Tags: c#, stream, windows-runtime, dispose, stream-socket-client

I've made a small class that connects to and IRC server, and now I'm trying to dispose of the socket.

Whenever I do so, i'm getting a

> The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or
>   an application request

It's maybe worth noting that I'm calling the dispose function

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

I've also tried Detaching the Stream from the DataReader before disposing the StreamSocket, but it still won't work. In fact it is raising another error.

> The operation identifier is not valid

How else am I supposed to dispose of the StreamSocket?

This is how I imagined the Dipose method should look like:

```
public async void Dispose()
{
     _closing = true;
     if (_connected)
          SendRawMessage("QUIT :");
     //_dataReader.DetachStream();
     await _clientSocket.DisposeAsync();
     _dataReader.Dispose();
     _connected = false;
     _closing = false;
}
```

When I connect I do it like so:

```
await _clientSocket.ConnectAsync(hostname, Port.ToString());
_connected = true;
_dataReader = new DataReader(_clientSocket.InputStream) { InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial };
ReadData();
```

The read data method is recursive and keeps on reading any incoming data:

```
async private void ReadData() {
    if (!_connected || _clientSocket == null || _closing == true) return;
    uint s = await _dataReader.LoadAsync(1024);
    string data = _dataReader.ReadString(s);
    ReadData();
}
```

Comment: You are disposing it while the socket is in use, actively trying to receive something.  That's okayish, but of course you get a "this is not normal" exception when the receive completes, it didn't actually receive anything.  The "or an application request" clause clearly applies.  Since you entirely *expect* this to happen, you can catch the exception.  Post better snippets if you need more help.

Comment: But calling DeteachStream on the datareader, doesn't that stop it from actively trying to receive data?

Comment: I've added some more code to show the context :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation is basically crap for `StreamSocket` and `DataReader`, but it seems likely from the behavior you're witnessing that you're not allowed to detach a stream while an I/O operation is in progress. In the normal .NET API (you seem to be using WinRT here...you should update your tags and post to make that clear), you terminate I/O operations by closing the socket and catching the subsequent `ObjectDisposedException`. Seems reasonable you'd do something similar here, just it's a different exception (apparently).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to cancel the read operation on the socket first. Fort his, use a `CancellationToken`.

Create a global `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

When calling `DataReader.LoadAsync()` pass a token:

```
uint s = await _dataReader.LoadAsync(1024).AsTask(
    cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

Finally, when you want to abandon everything, call cancel:

```
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

However, in this case, the `LoadAsync()` call will end with `TaskCanceledException`.

You don't need to dispose the socket anymore, the socket will be closed as part of cancelling the read operation.

Comment: This seems to be working really well :) how do you suppress the TaskCanceledException? Currently I've just placed the function within a try catch block, is this acceptable, or is there a better way?